# SQL Server 2012 via native C++ (no ATL) preferred access method from Windows

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, oledb

I have a native C++ application that runs under Windows 64, it doesn't use ATL (and will not). I want to be able to connect from my application to SQL Server 2012 over the network.

I have the following requirements:

- Performance is the key
- The C++ will only insert records (say by calling Stored Procs), nothing else (no selects, deletes or updates).
- Record insertions should be non-blocking (async).

I narrowed my choices down to OLE DB and ODBC as they satisfy the criteria above. However, it seems that the Internet have loads of contradicting advice of what to use. Examples:

- "If you have a choice between using ODBC or OLE DB to access your SQL Server database, choose OLE DB, as it is generally faster. [7.0, 2000, 2005] Updated 2-20-2006" source: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/odbc-oledb/
- "OLE DB is deprecated" source: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/09/04/rip-ole-db.aspx
- "Avoid using OLE DB for new SQL Server application development. Update your technology roadmap to move towards migrating existing SQL Server applications that use the SQLNCLI, SQLNCLI10, **SQLNCLI11** or SQLOLEDB OLE DB providers to the SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver."  source: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/09/04/rip-ole-db.aspx but SQLNCLI11 is the SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver based on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms130904.aspx so, was it a typo in the blog?

**I am really confused and would like to take more opinions on the best technology to access SQL Server with my criteria.**

Comment: Consider that just because something is deprecated does not mean you can't use it. There are unsupported SQL Server 2000 boxes all over the world, on operating systems that are long past their sunset, and those applications continue to run even though much of the software they're running have long been deprecated. I'm not saying that's an argument for using old crap in favor of new, but since you're using C++ by choice, maybe there are worse things you could do...

Comment: Native Client setup includes an OLE DB provider (SQLNCLIxx) and an ODBC driver. SQLNCLI11 is an OLE DB provider, it is not the "SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver". Just use ODBC.

Comment: @wqw is this an example of usage of what you are talking about? http://blog.nhaslam.com/2011/12/19/going-native-with-sql-server-introduction/ even though it is including sqlncli.h?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both OleDB and ODBC use the SQLNCLI. See the [Component Names and Properties by Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131291.aspx) table, observer how Sqlncli.dll/Sqlncli10.dll/Sqlncli11.dll is the driver for both ODBC and OleDB.

If you look at [Data Access Technologies Road Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#bkmk_CurrentMDAC_WDACArch) you'll see that both ODBC and OleDB are current and supported. What is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#bkmk_DepMDAC_WDACComps) is SQLOLEDB and SQLODBC, which are the old MDAC SQL Server drives for OleDB and ODBC (ie. sqlsrv32.dll and Sqloledb.dll). For both of them there are upgrade paths and recomendations, see [Updating an Application to SQL Server Native Client from MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035.aspx).

So the conclusion is that you can safely continue to use both ODBC and OleDB, just make sure you use the modern SLNCLI based drivers and not the old, deprecated, MDAC drivers.

The main risk in using deprecated drivers is lack of support for new data types (eg. geography, hierachy, datetime2 etc etc).

Comment: Close, but not quite. SQLNCLI is deprecated too, moving forward. The ODBC replacement is "Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Windows". There is no OLEDB replacement.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2013/01/23/introducing-the-new-microsoft-odbc-drivers-for-sql-server.aspx

From your own link:
"After SQL Server 2012, the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider will no longer be included in SQL Server Native Client."

Comment: Meanwhile, OLE DB drivers got de-depreacated.
So currently Microsoft offers [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server) for OLEDB and [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) for ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced years ago OleDB (with ATL) and ODBC (with MFC).

But the interface is seldom a bottleneck, usually inserting/updating dominate the time (actually, I performed large insert/update with bulkcopy + stored procedures).

Anyway, I would suggest an intermediate (a third ?) way: [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/), that make C++ / ODBC bearable.

Comment: I had a look, it is using STD templates and I am more fan of the C style approach of ODBC functions. I am not concerned about the complexity of code as it is insert only (and one insert statement).

Comment: You tagged C++ your question, and then I suggested the best interface I know. But 'de gustibus...'

Comment: You are right on this one, I wasn't really precise on this point as my focus was on the three mentioned criteria (performance, insert and async).

Comment: Anyway, OTL can't be compared to ODBC C interface, it's *much more* high level